# Combining both without affecting other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, merge

In here I have a photography portfolio and top navigation bar build separately. But when i try to combine it the styling changes? Why does that happens? Can someone help me to combine me both of it together without any changes to the styling. Thank you very much. Thank you very much. Thank you very much.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fefdfc;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #fefdfc 0%, #473146 74%);
    height: auto;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: black 3px 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

main {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#landing {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #000000 0%, #04619f 74%);
}

#landing-text {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 40vw;
    height: 50vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

#landing-text h2 {
    color: #b91300;
}

#landing-image {
    background: url(/images/camera.webp);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50vh;
    flex: 0 1 60vw;
    margin: 0;
}

.btn {
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2rem 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: background 500ms ease;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.11);
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

#header {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #000000 0%, #434343 74%);
    color: #fff;
}

#header h2 {
    border-left: dotted 1px #fff;
    border-right: dotted 1px #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.caption {
    padding: 0.8rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #fff;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    margin: auto;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

footer h3 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.social-part .fa {
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li a {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.navcolor {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.dropdown-menu {
    border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Screen Sizes 500px and Up */

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    #landing {
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #landing-text {
        height: 100vh;
    }
    #landing-image {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}


/* Screen Sizes 700px and Up */

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .btn {
        padding: 1rem 3rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Naveen Jc Photography</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <!-- Landing Area -->
        <div id="landing">
            <div id="landing-text">
                <div id="landing-text-inner">
                    <h1>Naveen <br> Photography</h1>
                    <h2 class="text">Beautiful Natural Photography</h2>
                    <a href="#images" class="btn" id="view-work">
                        View Work
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="landing-image"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="images">
            <div id="header">
                <h2>Our Work</h2>
            </div>

            <img src="/images/img1.webp" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo One</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/img2.webp" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Two</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/img3.webp" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Three</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/img4.webp" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Four</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/img5.webp" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Five</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
        <p>Email or call us to set up a consult</p>
        <p>Email:
            <strong>contact@jc.lensational</strong>
        </p>
        <p>Phone:
            <strong>(617) 212-5267</strong>
        </p>
    </footer>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

NAVIGATION BAR

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,500i,700,800i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Naveen Jc Photography</title>
</head>

<body class="navbody">

    <div class="navcolor">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark ">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown dmenu">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Our Services
                    </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu sm-menu dropdown-hover">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CORPORATE PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EVENT PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SOCIAL MEDIA AND EMAIL MARKETING PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PORTRAIT PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- <li class="nav-item dropdown dmenu">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sm-menu">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a>
                    </div>
                  </li> -->
                </ul>
                <div class="social-part">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.navbar-light .dmenu').hover(function() {
                $(this).find('.sm-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(150);
            }, function() {
                $(this).find('.sm-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(105)
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add screenshot of actual & expected layout to the question

Comment: Hi! please read about html document structure! You can in one HTML document use <html>, <body>, <head> tags only ones

Answer (score 0):

Please read [introduction to HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp) first.

You try to place two html documents in one file its not **unacceptable**

You need merge two files in one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div> NAVIGATION </div>
<div> other code of page </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i did. I did not paste that here because i already deleted it. I pasted everything in the body elements, links & javascript. It's working but the styling has changed.